# How to connect my domain (ex -: www.xyz.com) by hosting server Microsoft azure?

Tags: azure, azure-dns

My domain register from godaddy site I don't know how to connect this domain form an azure server. I have added these DNS server names in godaddy.

```
ns1-03.azure-dns.com.
ns2-03.azure-dns.net.
ns3-03.azure-dns.org.
ns4-03.azure-dns.info.
```

Is it right or wrong? How do i manage my domain's DNS in Azure?

Comment: Looks right, you need to update the parent domain with the Azure DNS name servers. make sure you copy the trailing period at the end of the address. You can use a tool such as `nslookup` to query the Start of Authority (SOA) record for your zone. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns#delegate-the-domain

Comment: You have to add the domain to Azure DNS Zone to get the correct NS record. It not a guessing game.

Answer (score 1):

What it shows you by nslookup?

If you can see those NS code, yes right.

When your domain issued, you can see what name server(NS) using in your domain by nslookup or any nslookup web services.

- Make sure, your domain issued, it would take times until get your domain more than 2days or less depends on domain service companies.

These NS value would print on your prompt or cmd querying domain.

```
       ns1-03.azure-dns.com.

       ns2-03.azure-dns.net.

       ns3-03.azure-dns.org.

       ns4-03.azure-dns.info.
```

Comment: when i run (nslookup ns1-03.azure-dns.com)                                                     
                    Server:         168.**.**.**
                   Address:        168.**.***.**#53

                  ** server can't find ns2-03.azure-dns.com: NXDOMAIN

Comment: Godaddy has a DNS setting page or would has a Name server(NS) setting page separately. When you find it, enter per each NS codes.

Comment: Oh it’s not ‘nslookup ns1-03.azure-dns.com’. Type it as ‘nslookup www.example.com’ or nslookup/ set query=ns/ www.example.com

Comment: See this page. http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/using-nslookup/